# How to know the direction of one 3D vector compared with two other 3D vectors?

Tags: vectors

Let's say I have three (normalized) vectors pictured here:

[image]

I want to know how to figure out if Vector $C$ is to the right of Vector $A$ in relation to Vector $B$.

Let "Right" = Vector $B$ and "Forward" = Vector $A$, and "Up" is the blue line in this particular picture.

All three vectors always rotate together, like so:

[image]

I think this is an easy math question, and I already know that if $C$ is perfectly up then that should equal $-+A$ cross $B$, if $C$ is perfectly right then $C = B$, etc etc.

But I'm not sure how to do the same thing for non $-90$ degree turns, like the first couple pictures, or like this picture here:

[image]

In this case it is still "Up" (not perfectly so), but I'm not sure how to determine that.

I'm not great at math so simpler answers preferred :)

Here is an example (XYZ):

$C$ =  (-0.5789, 0.5260, 0.6231)

$A$ = (-0.0914, 0.7565, 0.6476)

$B$ = (0.9635, 0.2314, -0.1343)

In this case C is to the left. This isn't a homework question by the way, I just whipped these up in a 3D program.

Comment: You need karma to embed images? There are 3 of them in the Q.

Comment: That's what it said. I think someone edited them in though for me.

Comment: Yes, the user with beautiful name 311411 has enough karma.

Comment: Is right defined as $B$, or as $b$ such that $b \cdot A = 0, b\cdot B > 0, A, B, b$ are coplanar?

Comment: B dot A = 0, yes, and B dot B >0, also yes. They will always be axis aligned like the pictures showed. So any which way up or down, but not down and left, for example.

Comment: regardless, if you dot $C$ with the correct definition of "right", it's more right than left if the dot product is positive. it's more left than right if the dot product is negative. i can edit this into an answer if you clarify the question.

Comment: so A is always perpendicular to B, but C moves freely?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, $C$ is to the right of $A$ if and only if $B \cdot C > 0$.

Since $B \times A$ is up, then similarly $C$ is up if and only if $B \times A \cdot C > 0$.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I also needed to know whether it's up or down, too, sorry if I didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: @LukasKawalec Hint: if $B$ is right and I dot that with $C$ to figure out if $C$ is right. Then if $B \times A$ is up ...

Comment: A is always forward. I understand that if C is neither to the right of left A then B dot C is 0. But C dot A only tells me if it's behind or in front of A, not up or down. But I imagine I can figure it out from here with the information you provided and my own research.

Comment: Thank you for editing your comment. I've got it now.